Are there sets that are so unique that even multisets can't share a sum with them?
For sets that don't have $1$s or $0$s and all numbers are whole numbers.
We already know $A$ = {$a,b,c...$} and it has distinct subset sums.
For multisets consisting of only elements from $A$, can we generate sets that are so unique that
$\sum_{x \in A} x \neq \sum_{y \in MULTI-SET} y$ ?
We don't want any arbitrary multiset like {$a,a,a,b,b,c......$} summing up $A$.
We don't have to include all elements from $A$ in an arbitrary multiset to possibly sum up to $A$?
I would find it very interesting if we can generate these unique sets without large numbers.

Having distinct subset sums is a stronger condition than being a Sidon set, and I don't understand what it means for a multiset to "sum up to $A$". Can you be more precise about the condition you're looking for?

@Misha Lavrov Let's say that a multiset summed up to all the numbers in $A$. If we allowed $1$s we'll just use a multiset consisting of sum(A) $1$s but that's too easy. I wanted to know if it were possible to generate sets that are so unique that there's no possible way for a multiset to sum up to $A$. Edit: Only allowing elements from $A$

what does "so unique"   mean?

@WillJagy "So unique" means that particular set is the only way to sum up to that set. While only using those elements in that set.

If your set $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, it seems you want the only solution to
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i,\  x_i \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\} $$
to be all $x_i = 1$.  Yes, it's quite possible, even easy.
Try $A = \{p, q\}$ where $p < q$ are coprime integers $ > 1$.  Note that the integer solutions to $p x_1 + q x_2 = p + q$ are
$x_1 =  1 - q s$, $x_2 = 1 + p s$ where $s$ is an integer.  To have $x_1 \ge 0$ we need $s \le 0$, but for $x_2 \ge 0$ we need $s \ge 0$.  So the only possibility is $s = 0$, i.e. $x_1 = x_2 = 1$.
Examples with more numbers are more complicated, but e.g. you might enjoy showing that $A = \{4, 6, 7\}$ works.
[EDIT] Suppose
$A_n = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ is an example with $n$ numbers, where
$a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n = s$.  Take $t$ where
$t > s$ and $t \equiv 1 \mod n$.  Then I claim
$A_{n+1} = \{n a_1, n a_2, \ldots, n a_n, t\}$ is an example.
Its sum is $n s + t$, so we're looking for nonnegative integer solutions of
$n x_1  a_1 + n x_2 a_2 + \ldots + n x_n a_n + x_{n+1} t = n s + t$.
Taking this mod $n$, we see that $x_{n+1} \equiv 1 \mod n$. If $x_{n+1} = 1$, the equation reduces to $x_1 a_1 + \ldots + x_n a_n = s$, and by assumption the only nonnegative integer solution of this is $x_1 = \ldots = x_n = 1$.  Otherwise, $x_{n+1} \ge n + 1$, but that makes $x_{n+1} t \ge n t + t > n s + t$.
By induction, we get examples for all $n \ge 2$.
